# Access values from array depending on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray`. If I select 1st index of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I should be able to fetch value at 1st index from NSMutableArray and so on. anotherTempArray is `NSMutableArray`. Will be thankful for suggested logic. Here's what I am trying.
 [image]

Comment: Let me get this straight -- you want to know how to index an NSMutableArray?  Have you bothered to look at the documentation??  (You should not be programming in Objective-C until you have some basic concepts down.)

Comment: do suggest me some link which will clear the confusion between nsarray and nsmutablearray.

Comment: They are the same, except that you can change an NSMutableArray, while an NSArray is read-only.  (One thing to understand about Apple's documentation:  To see, eg, all the methods on, say, NSMutableArray, go to that doc page and then click on the link to the superclass of NSMutableArray (which is NSArray) near the top of the page.  Do this again on NSObject at the top of the NSArray page to see even more stuff.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[anotherTempArray objectAtIndex:y]` would return some object stored in the object.

While you are comparing it with  and integer i.e. `indexPath.row`

If you want to access the value from the array based on your selcected row, do as:

```
NSLog(@"%@",anotherTempArray[indexPath.row]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get value from array depending on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` by wirting the below code in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method :

```
NSLog(@"%@",[anotherTempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

And just remove "y" and put `indexPath.row`,in your `[anotherTempArray objectAtIndex:y]` code.

Answer (score 0):

Your picture isn't loading, but are you looking for something similar to this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id object = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Do Stuff
}
```